# Path to file used as environment variable

Tags: c++, macos

My C++ code for outputting content to a file is:

```
fstream myfile;

myfile.open("file.txt", ios::in);
if(!myfile.is_open()) cout << "error";
```

I want my code to function in the following way:
If `file.txt` is located in the same directory as the built executable or the cpp file, then my code should open the file.

Currently this is not the case. When I checked the location of the current working directory with `getcwd` it showed `/User/myusername` instead of `/User/myusername/Desktop` where all the files actually are located.

Comment: You should write more that one very long and hard to understand sentence and explain in detail what you are trying to do otherwise we won't be able to help and consequently you will be very frustrated because we won't help you at all so please rephrase your question so that we have a chance to understand it ! Am I clear ?

Comment: @hivert i did rephrase the questions as good as i could

Comment: How are your launching the executable ? It should be launched in the current directory.

Comment: @hivert I am launching it by double-clicking the icon of the executable(black terminal screen as an icon)